# Azure DevOps PowerShell Json to text file - Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops

I have an azure devops pipeline that I'd like to write the content of a variable that holds json to a text file.

Here are two tasks from the pipeline:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
             displayName: 'echo swagger content'
             inputs:
               script: |
                 echo "print value of swaggerContent output variable set in get-swagger-from-azure.ps1"
                 echo $(swaggerContent)

           - task: PowerShell@2
             displayName: 'write swagger content to file'
             inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: $env:swaggerContent | Out-File "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/swagger-content.json"'
```

The CmdLine task works ok and outputs the json, as seen below:

[image]

However, the PowerShell task gives the following error:

> At D:\a_temp\05c70744-c4cc-4322-99a0-98f55e41fbba.ps1:7 char:1
>
> - } else {
> - ~ Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If as you say, the content is already _a variable that holds json_, then why use `ConvertTo-Json` in your script?

Comment: Hi Theo, that was me guessing at a solution! I got the same error without ConvertTo-Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(swaggerContent)` is an Azure Pipelines variable, not a PowerShell variable. It's just a placeholder that contains the JSON.

So in the line

```
$(swaggerContent) | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/swagger-content.json"
```

Think of what happens if you just replace `$(swaggerContent)` with some JSON. You get something like

```
{ "foo": "bar" } | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/swagger-content.json"
```

Note that the JSON is **completely unescaped**. It's not a string, it's just random text inserted in the middle of the script.

Azure Pipelines treats non-secret variables as environment variables when running scripts, so you can try something along the lines of:

```
$env:swaggerContent | Out-File "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/swagger-content.json"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but that gives: At D:\a\_temp\05c70744-c4cc-4322-99a0-98f55e41fbba.ps1:7 char:1
+ } else {
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
I provide updated detail in the question

Comment: ah - I missed an apostrophe - 2 mins...